# Fermat Last Theorem in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, math

i was asked to create an algorithm that prints all the possible combinations for the equation a^n+b^n=c^n **without duplicates**.
the given input was a limit and the pow of the numbers.
i used 3 nested loops in order to solve this(no complicity limits) but i couldn't solve the duplicates problem.
for example,

input: 2(pow),20(limit)

my output:
3,4,5

4,3,5

5,12,13

6,8,10

8,6,10

8,15,17

9,12,15

12,5,13

12,9,15

12,16,20

15,8,17

16,12,20

correct output:

3,4,5

5,12,13

6,8,10

8,15,17

9,12,15

```
 public static void Fermat(int n,int range) {
        int temp = 0;
        double x, y, z;
        for (int a = 1; a <= range; a++) {
            for (int b = 1; b <= range; b++) {
                for (int c = 1; c <= range; c++) {
                    x = Math.pow(a, n);
                    y = Math.pow(b, n);
                    z = Math.pow(c, n);
                    if (x + y == z) {
                        System.out.println(a + "," + b + "," + c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about you only check triples where `a < b < c`?

Comment: yep, that worked, thank you

Comment: So `6,8,10` and `9,12,15` are permitted?  They are essentially equivalent to the primitive triple `3,4,5` times a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Try tightening your restrictions:

```java
for (int a = 1; a <= range; a++) {
    for (int b = a; b <= range; b++) {
        for (int c = b; c <= range; c++) {
...
```

Comment: A couple of points.  if `n > 2`  you can just return since it has been proven that no solution exists.  For your loops, you can eliminate some tests by letting `int  b = a+1` and `int c = b+1` in your loops.